# How could I go about modifying (or building) a hand dryer to be more efficient?

Tags: appliances, dryer

I find myself spending a fair amount of time in my workshop as a result of some newly acquired hobbies (painting an building things), and a seemingly equal amount of time in the kitchen as a result of long-held necessities (preparing and eating food). And as I don't like having paint-covered hands for cooking, raw-food covered hands for eating, or food-covered hands for working, I find myself spending a large amount of time washing and drying my hands.

In my quest to become more efficient, I'm trying to eliminate an obnoxious time sink: hand drying. Wet hands are an obvious no-go (chapped skin), and towels are either unsanitary (used) or incredibly wasteful (disposable). That leaves hand dryers, and though I'm pretty happy with the one I've bought (TOTO Clean Dry), it leaves me thinking that there has to be a faster way. Especially after learning about the Leidenfrost effect.

How should I go about creating or modifying a hand dryer to provide an intense burst of heat during the initial drying stages? I've experimented with foot-controlled 0.5  to 1.5 second propane bursts with some success, but it did singe a few hairs on my arm… and I'd hate to catch my sleeves on fire.

Are there faster ways to dry my hands than by using a high-pressure air dryer (like mine, Dyson Blade, etc)?

Comment: I wouldn't modify your hand dryer at all. Heat generating appliances are not thing you typically want to be modifying on your own.

Comment: This is a bit crazy. Playing with large bursts of open propane flame merely to dry your hands is dangerous to you and potentially to others. One second of inattention will leave you with serious burns, or may kill someone else who inadvertently uses your contraption without knowing what you have done. If you are going back and forth so many dozens of times between places every day that the seconds spent drying your hands is truly a problem, then just arrange your schedule more carefully.

Comment: Check out this:  The airflow acts like a squeegee to pull the excess water off your skin, and then blow dries the rest.  Probably expensive.  They don't even quote a price on the website.

Comment: -1 because this isn't something that anyone else should do... and from your past experience, neither should you.

Comment: I fail to see how this is considered off-topic while there's a whole tag dedicated to dryers and other appliances.... but fair enough. I appreciate @woodchips suggestion, that's probably for the best.

Comment: Encouraging anyone to do something like build a hand dryer from an open propane flame is nothing that should ever be recommended on this site. Suppose someone tried it, and potentially died from the resulting burns from an experiment gone wrong? Can you spell lawsuit?

Comment: Hand dryers would be considered a small appliance, and OT per the [faq]. If you look at the other dryer questions, you'll see they are referring to a clothes dryer. Even if this wasn't considered a small appliance, it would be considered too localized since no one should be doing this and therefore the answers wouldn't be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dyson Airblade and the Xlerator hand dryer are both really fast and effective.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Please see the [faq#promotion] for the rules on promoting products that you're affiliated with.

Comment: The TOTO Clean Dry is what I currently have and, while not as luxurious as the Airblade, it's equally fast.

Comment: "really fast and effective". Counterpoint: no, they are just really (_really_) loud.

Answer (score 3):

Get a box of cheap disposable vinyl gloves, like [these, which are $40 for 1000 gloves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MWA4F2). That way you won't have to wash paint, varnish, etc. off your hands as often. You could probably use them several times in most circumstances.

(If the disposability bothers you, consider that creating and using a custom hand-drier has its own environmental impact--the electricity (or propane) required to run it, plus all the embodied energy in the materials, trip to Home Depot to buy parts, etc.)